# Poner una celda en color rojo desde un td con una clase creado dinamicamente?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy creando el cuerpo de una tabla dinamicamente por jquery, en el td le asigno la clase rojo para poner el color de la celda en rojo

en al css le aplico:

```
.rojo{
    border-width: 1px;
   border-color:red;
 }


function imprimirDatos(div, item) {
   var cadena = "<tr class='columna'>";
   cadena = "<td class='rojo'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'>"
   cadena = "<td> <input class='año' value='" + item.año + "'></td> "
   div.append(cadena);
 }
```

El borde de la celda no cambia de color, no se si es porque se esta creando dinamicamente o por bootstrap pero le aplico !important y tampoco la pinta.

**Edicion**

No tengo mas en el css.
Pienso que el problema puede estar en el bootstrap

Comment: Puedes colocar código que permita reproducir tu problema? Inspeccionaste el elemento para ver si alguna de tus dos reglas están siendo sobreescritas por otras clases?

Comment: Conesas lineas de Código no podemos ayudarte a decir que esta pasando y menos en ayudarte a solucionar el problema

Comment: ya intentaste con `!important`?

Comment: intenta con `.rojo{
    border: 1px solid red;
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falta `border-style`:

```
border-style:solid;
```

intenta con

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

tampoco veo donde cierras `td` en

```
"<td class='rojo'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'>"
```

deberia ser

```
"<td class='rojo'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'></td>"
```

tampoco veo donde cierras `tr`

```css
.rojo{
    border-width: 1px;
   border-color:red;

 }

.rojo2{
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 .rojo3{
  border-width: 1px;
   border-color:red;
    border-style:solid;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class='rojo'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'></td>
<td class='rojo2'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'></td>
<td class='rojo3'> <input class='ciudad' value='" + item.ciudad + "'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```